# OSX stuck in logon screen

Tags: macos, mac, sleep, macos-sierra

I have Macbook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014 (MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.6).

Since a week ago, whenever I wake up the laptop from a long sleep - its freezes:

- The login screen is being displayed.
- The cursor is inside the password field and it's blinking endlessly.
- The laptop is not responding to the trackpad or any of the keyboard keys, except the power button which turns the screen off and on (when it's on again - it enters the same state).

The only thing I'm able to do is to long-press the power button until the OS restarts.
The OS is responding normally after that boot, closing the lid and re-opening it after a short while - works normally.

What can I do to solve it so the laptop will wake out of sleep mode?

Comment: Have you looked at the System Log or any other logs for clues? Have you tried plugging in an external USB keyboard (or even a Bluetooth keyboard for that matter) to see if the problem is specific to the built-in keyboard/trackpad?

Comment: I guess there is no problem with the built-in keyboard/mouse, because after the reboot they were working well. I did the steps listed here and it didn't happend so far: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-reset-mac-pram-or-nvram-2260839. Thx for your response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the steps listed under the headline `Resetting the Parameter RAM` in the following article:
https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-reset-mac-pram-or-nvram-2260839

And it didn't happen again so far...